# combine keys and values to add in object

Tags: object, underscore.js

I need to add some pre-defined properties (from an array) into my object.
Eg.

```
var x = {"p":1};
var add_keys = ["p1", "p2", "p3"];
var add_vals = [ 10 ,  '',   20 ];

// simplest way, but not generic as add_keys use:
[x['p1'],x['p2'],x['p3']] = add_vals;  // but not need empty p2
// perhaps clean with _.omitBy(x, _.isNil);
```

So this function solves the problem:

```
function obj_addByKeysVals(obj,keys,vals,canEmpty=false) {
  for (var i=0; i<vals.length;i++) {
    var val = vals[i];
    var key = keys[i];
    if (canEmpty||val) obj[key] = val;
  }
  return obj;
}


x = obj_addByKeysVals(x, ['p1','p2','p3'], add_vals);
```

I wold like to do *obj_addByKeysVals* directly **with underscore** (eg. using a kind of `_.zip`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of [**extend**](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) and [**object**](http://underscorejs.org/#object):

```
var x = {"p":1};
var add_keys = ["p1", "p2", "p3"];
var add_vals = [ 10 ,  '',   20 ];

var result = _.extend(x, _.object(add_keys, add_vals));
```

Comment: Perfect!  Hum... And about something like `_.omitBy(x, _.isNil)` but works as my js code?  (see the check `if (val) obj[key] = val`)